# getting custom dateTime format from DateTime.TryParse

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I read cell values from excel file that has a several data type (string , dateTime , int) .
And In DateTime cell , that may be in various format likes `12/28/2013` , `8:30` .

Using this code , ( `cell.ToString()` is excel cell value )

```
DateTime _dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(cell.ToString(), out _dt))
{
   //
}
```

When I read `12/28/2013` , it return `12/28/2013 12:00:00 AM` .
But when I read `8:30` ,  it return `12/31/1899 12:00:00 AM` .
As you can see , I can't get the original time `8:30` .
Am I wrong something ?
OR is there any approach to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TryParseExact` and specify your formats. There is an overload taking `string[]` patterns array as a parameter:

[`DateTime.TryParseExact` Method (`String`, `String[]`, `IFormatProvider`, `DateTimeStyles`, `DateTime`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can call it like that:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(cell.ToString(), new [] { "M/d/yyyy", "hh:mm" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out _dt);
```

You may need [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prepare more patterns to make sure it works for all your input formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
string strDate = "8:00";
string format = "hh:mm";
DateTime res;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out res);
```